# installing nvidia drivers and control panel

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 12.04.

I downloaded the nvidia drivers but couldn't get the .run file to work

I installed the drivers for my GTX 570 via the additional drivers control panel and it says that they are active.

When I open System-> details -> graphics it says that The driver is ubnknown.

When I perform a search for "nvidia" all i get is the nvidia X server settings control panel.

I tried apt-get install nvidia-settings and it said that it installed it but I can't find it anywhere.

have I successfully installed 1) The drivers 2) The Control panel.

if 2) is true how can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA X server settings is your driver control panel.